# Derivative for Masked Matrix Hadamard Multiplication

Tags: vector-analysis, hadamard-product

In deep learning, such an operation is common:

$$A = B\circ (C>0.2)$$

where $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\circ$ denotes Hadamard Multiplication and $C>0.2$ is the matrix where each element is itself when it is larger than $0.2$ and is masked as $0$ otherwise.

I want to know the partial derivative for $A$ with respect to $C$, formally $$\frac{\partial A}{\partial C}$$

Comment: For any $A,B,C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, the following is true :$$\frac{\partial(A \circ B)}{\partial(C)} = \frac{\partial(A)}{\partial(C)} \circ B + A \circ \frac{\partial(B)}{\partial(C)}$$

Comment: Please give an equation of how such computation ever happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}\def\bb{\mathbb}$It's
simpler use the `vec()` operator and deal with a vector equation in
$\,{\bb R}^{mn\times 1}$
$$a = b\circ (c>\lambda)$$
Make the following definitions
$$\eqalign{
z &= c-\lambda\o
\qquad&(\lambda\,{\rm is\,an\,arbitrary\,scalar}) \\
{\cal H}(z_k) &= \begin{cases}1\quad{\rm if}\quad z_k>0\\0\quad{\rm otherwise} \end{cases}
\qquad&({\rm Heaviside\,step\,function}) \\
h &= {\cal H}(z)
\qquad&({\rm apply\,the\,function\,elementwise}) \\
}$$
Write the problem in terms of the above, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
a &= b\circ h\circ c \\
da &= b\circ h\circ dc
  \;=\; \D(b\circ h)\; dc \\
\grad{a}{c} &= \D(b\circ h) \\\\
}$$

---

Note that the quantity
$G=\left(\grad{a}{c}\right)$
calculated above is a
${\bb R}^{mn\times mn}$ matrix whereas the requested quantity
$\Gamma=\left(\grad{A}{C}\right)\in{\bb R}^{m\times n\times m\times n}$
which is a fourth-order tensor.
The individual elements are identical
$\big({\rm e.g.}\;\Gamma_{1111}=G_{11}\big);\,$
the tensor has simply been *reshaped* into a matrix.

The elements of the matrix can be reshaped into a tensor, if that is the desired form. Personally I use Julia and find the matrix form more convenient to work with, since I can use regular built-in matrix*vector product as opposed to writing explicit for-loops.

Consider the matrix calculation

```
G,dc  = rand(m*n,m*n), rand(m*n)
da = G*dc
```

versus the tensor calculation

```
Γ,dC,dA = reshape(G,m,n,m,n), reshape(dc,m,n), zeros(m,n)
for i = 1:m
  for j = 1:n
    for k = 1:m
      for l = 1:n
        dA[i,j] += Γ[i,j,k,l] * dC[k,l]
      end
    end
  end
end

norm(vec(dA) - da)  # approx == machine epsilon
```

Yes, there are tensor packages available, but it's still awkward compared to working with vectors and matrices.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the following operation:$$a = b\circ h\circ c\implies da=b\circ h \circ dc$$
I think $c_i = b_i * h_i * c_i\implies \frac{\partial a_i}{\partial c_i} = b_i*h_i$, so $da=b\circ h \circ dc$. Am I right?

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with an explanation of how you could use `reshape()` to obtain the tensor, and how that's not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Also, the gradient requires **contraction** products, i.e. dot products.  Other types of products (such as a Hadamard, Kronecker, dyadic, or tensor product) will produce _something_, but it won't be a gradient.

Comment: Thank you greg. I think I misunderstood the local gradient, which is essentially the Jacobian Matrix(Tensor) and the gradient `PyTorch` used to update parameters, which is exactly the local gradient multiplying the gradient passed from the former layer. I can get what I want by simple matrix multiplication. But anyway thank you very much!